# In laravel, how can I echo out form results in json format, after submitting?

Tags: json, laravel

In laravel, how can I echo out form results in JSON format, after submitting; without saving to the database first? This is to check the data the form is holding.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be in json but it'd serve your purpose of checking data. 
You can simply do this in your controller to check what your request contains:

```
dd($request->all());
```

This would work for almost all version in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have already done form submit code with form. below one line code you can use in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   echo json_encode($request);
   // below you can store data after validation if need then
}
```

if you are using a post method to submit a form then above one line code will you to echo form data as json format

you can also check form data with Dump and Die like `dd($request->all());` but this will not return json format

*Note: if it's not working then please explain which php and Laravel version you are using.*

[Official  Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation)